# SqlTransaction “Object reference not set to an instance of an object”?

Tags: c#, transactions, sql-server-2008-r2

I use many transaction in my project : Like this :

```
bool retVal = true;
string errorCode = string.Empty;
try
 {
   result = RecordsDal.ReadAllDoneRecords();
   retVal = Export(result, out errorCode);
 }
catch
 {
    Errorlog(errorCode, ex.Message);
    MessageBox.Show("Error Export "+ Environment.NewLine + ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
    return false;            
 }
```

the export :

```
    public static bool Export(List<Record> result,  out string error)
    {
        bool retVal = true;
        error = "sqlCeConnection";
        SqlCeConnection sqlCeConnection = null;
        error = "Initializiong";
        SqlTransaction trans = null;
        try
        {
           error = "Begin";
           .......
           error = "End";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            trans.Rollback();
            retVal = false;                
        }
    }
```

and I use an error logs to Know where I have a problem,

the application work fine in many client but I install the app in the new one and I have an error with the file log have the code error and the exception ex.Message

> Initializing : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

the error in this line : `SqlTransaction trans = null;`

**sorry, I found the real problem, the sqlCe not installed, and there's ex.innerexception = null the the log have save this error not the real one**

Comment: Can you post the exact line of code where the exception occurs?  A stack trace would also help.  Where is `connection` set?

Comment: This is NRE, it can happen in many places. It occurs when you call a method on an object that is null. You should check your stack trace.

Comment: 2 things to check - is connection null? secondly, if the transaction isn't started, then you need to check for null before blindly rolling it back in your catch

Comment: I don't have this error in debug mode or in my test in many PCs and with all my clients, but this new one have this error I have to change the log with stack trace and change application to know

Comment: and about the connexion null, I work with this application about 6 month and this the first time, and the error in the line of declaration of SqlTransaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, I found the real problem, the sqlCe not installed, and there's ex.innerexception = null the the log have save this error not the real one

Answer (score 2):

If there was an error creating the transaction, the variable will never be set:

```
trans = connection.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted)
```

So `trans` will be `null`. As in you `catch` you expect `trans` to exist, you are creating this new exception that swallows the real one.

In order to get the actual exception, add this line before `trans.Rollback()`:

```
if(trans == null) throw;
```

This menas: if there's an error and the transaction wasn't created, throw the error.

Comment: but the error in this line : SqlTransaction trans = null;
the app haven't yet create the transaction

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense. Try what I suggest or paste the stack trace that says so.

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense. (yes I know) and ok I will make the stack trace, I will change the app and get it

Comment: So, the CodeError says "Initializing" but doesn't say "Begin"?

Comment: I mean, you are just giving the log value to a property and the code you've provided doesn't even compile (there are missing ;), so I couldn't be sure if that's the actual code you are executing, and it's more difficult to give a right diagnosis.

Comment: the logs function in the catch , car all the code that I wrote in another try catch, because I want to know where is the probleme

Comment: there is a lot to write  I can make it with some detail

Comment: Updated my code, I hope this help, and I will make the stack trace

Comment: You forgot the code that actually creates the transaction, and it continues not to compile as there's no `return`in that method. Anyway, could you provide the result of the log? Also, did you try adding the null validation before rolling back the transaction?

Comment: sorry, I found the real problem, the sqlCe not installed, and there's ex.innerexception = null the the log have save this error not the real one

Comment: And what method exactly raised the exception?